# Nesting React.js Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to call the render of a nested component within the render of a parent. This is what I've tried so far. Is there a pattern for this? Thanks.

```
var nest = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({
      className: 'boop' 
    }, 'hello')
  }
})

var comp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({
      className: 'beep', 
      children: React.renderComponent(nest(this.props))
    })
  }
})

React.renderComponent(comp(props), document.body)
```

Expected:

```
  <body>
    <div class='beep'>
      <div class='boop'>
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not let React handle the rendering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just pass it as a child:

```
var comp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return React.DOM.div({
      className: 'beep'
    }, nest(this.props))
  }
});
```

React.renderComponent is for declaring the root component and its mount point (sometimes multiple).  It isn't used within components.